# Pine Script entries exit on next bar even if TP/SL reached

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I cannot understand why **Pine Script** is exiting my position on next bar when I set **SL/TP**.

This is my simple example code:

```
if entryConditionsAreMet
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)

// let's assume 5% TP and 2% SL
takeProfitShort = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - (5 / 100))
stopLossShort = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + (2 / 100))

strategy.exit("exitShort", "short", limit=takeProfitShort, stop=stopLossShort)
```

It opens and closes positions correctly, however the TP/SL **always occur on the next bar**.

Look at the picture below to understand (the green line is the TP and the orange one is the SL):

[I'd expect the position closes on the same bar, not in the next one!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30gBA.png)

As you can see, the position closes not when the TP is reached but on the next opening bar.

Why does this happen? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if entryConditionsAreMet
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)

// let's assume 5% TP and 2% SL
takeProfitShort = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - (5.0 / 100))
stopLossShort = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + (2.0 / 100))

strategy.exit("exitShort", "short", limit=takeProfitShort, stop=stopLossShort)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **not currently possible** in pinescript (as far as I am aware) **but you can trigger an exit on the close of the entry bar**:

```
if exitConditionsAreMet
    strategy.close_all(comment, alert_message, immediately) //Set immediately to true
```

Using **`strategy.close_all()`** allows for closing entries on the same bar they are opened by setting the `immediately` parameter to true.

Both `strategy.exit()` and `strategy.entry()` will ignore the limit (take profit) and stop (stoploss) on the entry bar, and will be active criteria on the open of the following bar.